# How to mount child component outside parent using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that there is React portals that may solves the problem, but portals mount child components outside of DOM tree if I understand it correctly. But I need to render child component inside DOM tree but just outside the parent. Here the example.

I have a page:

```
const Page = () => {
  return (
         <>
           // -> the place to mount <Child_2/> <--
           <Parent/>
         </>)
```

I have the Parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
          <>
            <Child_1/>
            <Child_2/> //<- I need it NOT to mount here but outside the parent 
                       // in the <Page> component and not outside the DOM. 
          </>
)
```

How can I do it? And yet can I make it by portal?
In React doc I found an example just for case:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app-root"></div>
    <div id="modal-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it is not my case...

Comment: "but portals mount child components outside of DOM tree" - not sure thats true. Portals is exactly the tool for the job, or else restructure your components. From the docs - "Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component." - Isnt that what you want?

Comment: Here is React doc https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html and the example just for DOM case.

Comment: So based on the doc I just need to set id on Component?

Comment: try `ReactDOM.createPortal(<Child_2/>, document.body)`

Comment: you need to create a DOM node in your `Page` component, to be the target, then use `createPortal()` to mount your `Child2` component on the target DOM node.  Yes you could use an id to target the new DOM node, see here for a decent example - https://blog.logrocket.com/learn-react-portals-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
const Page = ()=> {
   const [el, setEl] = React.useState(null);
   return (
     <>
        <div ref={setEl}></div>
        {el && <Parent el={el} />}
     </>
   )
}
const Parent = ({el})=> {
   React.useEffect();
   return (
     <>
        <Child_1/>
        {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Child2 />,el)}
     </>
   )
}
```